# Trade off between layouts types

Tags: android, performance, memory, layout

In my app I have a layout which I can make in one `RelativeLayout` or with a nested `LinearLayout`s.

Is there a known trade off between the layouts? I mean, is there an equation like 1 RelativeLayout equals 3 nested LinearLayout or such?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the algorithm used by the `RelativeLayout` is more complex than the one used by the `LinearLayout`, what you are essentially asking is if "three LinearLayout worth more than a RelativeLayout" performance-wise.

We could probably delve into a lot of details about how each layout measures the contained views hierarchically and try to give a theoretical answer to the question, but the correct answer is, IMHO, that the only way to find out is to create both layouts and measure how long it take for each one of them to be measured. *When it comes to performances, profiling is always the solution (where excessive pre-emptive optimization rarely is...)*.

Keep also in mind that the profiling data might be of limited use anyway, as with each new iteration of the Android OS the developers might tweak and (hopefully) improve the algorithms used to place the views (therefore the data gathered from a 2.2 profiling session might not represent the results you would get in ICS).

Personally, I usually go with the multiple LinearLayout approach, as *I feel it's easier to read and modify*, but when I had to switch to a `RelativeLayout` I never noticed a significant degradation/improvement of performances

Hope this helps

Comment: ^ This, except when nesting RelativeLayouts which causes exponental layout passes